# Tensorflow: ''roulette wheel" selection

Tags: tensorflow

I try to implement roulette wheel selection in Tensorflow. So I started with this:

```
x = tf.random_uniform([tf.shape(probabilities)[0]])
cumsum = tf.cumsum(probabilities, axis=1) # cumulative sum
b = tf.greater_equal(x, cumsum) # Boolean values now 
...
indices = tf.where(b) # this given indices for all the True values, I need only the first one per row
indices = indices[:,1] # we only need column index
```

Any suggestions for this? Or a better procedure to do the roulette wheel selection?

So a small example to make it more clear

```
probabilities = [[0.2 0.3 0.5],
                 [0.1 0.6 0.3],
                 [0.5 0.4 0.1]]

x = [0.27, 0.86, 0.73] # drawn randomly
```

Then I want as output [1, 2, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to draw the samples from multinomial distribution. To do that, it is easiest to simply use [tf.multinomial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#multinomial):

```
samples = tf.multinomial(tf.log(probabilities), 1)
```

Possibly followed by reshaping:

```
samples_vector = tf.reshape(samples, [-1])
```